# Python text wrapping within a string template

Tags: python, string, word-wrap

I have strings of varying length that I'd like to print in a template as follows:

```
printTemplate = "{0:<5}|{1:<55}|{2:<20}"
print printTemplate.format("ID", "Text", "Category")
    for (docId, text, category) in textList:
        print printTemplate.format(docId, text, category)
```

Which comes out as,

```
ID   |Text                                                   |Category
1500 |Monet is the French painter I have liked the best      |Painting
...
```

The problem is the text strings are sometimes longer than 55 characters, which ruins the formatting. I've tried using TextWrapper,

```
from textwrap import TextWrapper
wrapper = TextWrapper(width=55)
...
        print printTemplate.format(docId, wrapper.fill(text), category)
```

But this doesn't seem to help. An ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PrettyTable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable) which will automatically format the output into columns.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable(["ID", "Text", "Category"])
for (docId, text, category) in textList:
    x.add_row([docId, text, category])
print x
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine truncating and padding as follows:

```
printTemplate = "{0:<5}|{1:55.55}|{2:<20}"
```

[This post](https://pyformat.info/#string_trunc_pad) may helps a lot by explaining various formatters with examples.